# VBA: Multiply a file (copy) and rename all after list

Tags: excel, vba

I had a .bat file that worked but I need this in VBA now.

I tried different approches but only managed to do this with one file at a time. So I keep starting over and over.

**So:**

1. I have a file (named 1.pdf)
2. I have on a excel on Sheet1 (starting with A2) a list of file names

I need VBA to create a folder named ABC (where-ever the Excel macro is located) and multiply 1.pdf as many times as needed and rename the copies with every name in the excel list.

**Example:**

(i have in the same folder as the macro 1.pdf) and in Excel:

A1

- John.pdf
- Dog.pdf
- Triangle.pdf

After execution this would result in 1.pdf copied and renamed with all of those 3 names uploaded into folder :ABC

In command prompt woud look like:

```
if not exist "ABC\" mkdir %cd%\ABC\
copy "1.pdf" "ABC"
ren "ABC\1.pdf" "John.pdf"
copy "1.pdf" "ABC"
ren "ABC\1.pdf" "Dog.pdf"
copy "1.pdf" "ABC"
ren "ABC\1.pdf" "Triangle.pdf"
```

Comment: if you have a working `.bat`, simply lauch it from VBA: `Shell myScript.bat`

Comment: Why copy&rename? Why _not_ `copy "1.pdf" "ABC\John.pdf"` (Does it have to be "ABC\\" because of the need to _escape_?)

Comment: Can you show the VBA code that copies the one file at a time? That's what you need help with, so a copy of it will help your potential helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub CopyFileForEachName()

    Dim rRenameList As Range
    Dim rNameCell As Range
    Dim sFileToCopyPath As String
    Dim sFolderPath As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sExt As String
    Dim sNewSubFolder As String
    Dim sCopyErr As String
    Dim sResultsMsg As String
    Dim lSuccessfulCopies As Long
    Dim i As Long

    'These are invalid characters for the subfolder name (the double quote "" will be evaluated as a single double quote")
    Const sInvalidChar As String = "\/:*?""<>|"

    If Len(ActiveWorkbook.Path) > 0 Then ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path        'Start in same folder as the active workbook
    sFileToCopyPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files, *.*")     'Prompt user to select file to copy
    If sFileToCopyPath = "False" Then Exit Sub  'Pressed cancel

    sFolderPath = Left(sFileToCopyPath, InStrRev(sFileToCopyPath, Application.PathSeparator))   'Extract the folder path
    sExt = Mid(sFileToCopyPath, InStrRev(sFileToCopyPath, "."))                                 'Extract the extension

    'Prompt user to select the range of cells that contain the rename list
    'Pressing cancel will cause an error, resume next will suppress the error and GoTo 0 will remove the On Error condition
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rRenameList = Application.InputBox("Select the cells that contain the rename list.", "Rename Cells Selection", Selection.Address, Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rRenameList Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    'If the list of rename cells is ALWAYS in the same location, you can comment out the above code, and uncomment the following:
    'With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    '    Set rRenameList = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    '    If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
    'End With

    'Prompt user to enter the destination subfolder name
    'Change the Default parameter to provide a desired default subfolder name
    sNewSubFolder = InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter the name of the subfolder that will store the copied and renamed files." & Chr(10) & _
                                     "Note that if the subfolder doesn't already exist, it will be created.", _
                             Title:="Destination Subfolder", _
                             Default:="ABC")
    If Len(Trim(sNewSubFolder)) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

    'Verify valid subfolder name
    For i = 1 To Len(sInvalidChar)
        sNewSubFolder = Replace(sNewSubFolder, Mid(sInvalidChar, i, 1), " ")
    Next i
    sNewSubFolder = WorksheetFunction.Trim(sNewSubFolder)
    If Right(sNewSubFolder, Len(Application.PathSeparator)) <> Application.PathSeparator Then sNewSubFolder = sNewSubFolder & Application.PathSeparator

    'Attempt to create the subfolder
    Err.Clear
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir sFolderPath & sNewSubFolder
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Failed to create the subfolder
        'Check if the folder already exists
        If Len(Dir(sFolderPath & sNewSubFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            'Subfolder does NOT exist, the provided subfolder name must be invalid
            MsgBox "Unable to create subfolder named [" & Replace(sNewSubFolder, Application.PathSeparator, "") & "] because it is an invalid name." & Chr(10) & "Exiting macro."
            Exit Sub
        Else
            'Subfolder already exists, got error due to duplicate name
            Err.Clear
        End If
    End If

    'Loop through each cell and rename the file
    For Each rNameCell In rRenameList.Cells
        'Make sure to use the extension of the file being copied
        If Right(rNameCell.Text, Len(sExt)) = sExt Then
            sFileName = Replace(rNameCell.Text, sExt, "")
        Else
            sFileName = rNameCell.Text
        End If

        'Attempt to copy and rename the file to the destination subfolder
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
        FileCopy sFileToCopyPath, sFolderPath & sNewSubFolder & sFileName & sExt
        On Error GoTo 0

        'Record successes and failures
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            sCopyErr = sCopyErr & Chr(10) & sFileName & sExt
        Else
            lSuccessfulCopies = lSuccessfulCopies + 1
        End If
    Next rNameCell

    'Build results message
    sResultsMsg = "Successfully copied [" & sFileToCopyPath & "] " & lSuccessfulCopies & " times into subfolder [" & sNewSubFolder & "]"
    If Len(sCopyErr) > 0 Then
        sResultsMsg = sResultsMsg & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Failed to copy with the following names: " & Chr(10) & sCopyErr
    End If

    'Display results message
    MsgBox sResultsMsg

End Sub
```

Comment: Only one mention, when i try to activate:     With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Linkuire")
        Set rRenameList = .Range("C2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'No data
    End With <BR> it says: Run time error 438, Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I think it was because of the formulas. Even if the cell was "" (empty) it has formulas running in it. I only need to take into account cells that have value (ignoring the cells with formulas that have no output - ex. " " )